# Best ways to implement Alarms into React Native?

Tags: react-native, alarm

I need to add the alarm functionality into my react-native app. An alarm that you have to manually stop/snooze [like these ones](https://www.androidauthority.com/alarm-clock-apps-android-101618/) . For that I have been browsing to know which library should I implement. These were the ones I found.

1. [react-native-alarms](https://github.com/upvalue/react-native-alarms): But only works for android...
2. [react-native-alarm -notification](https://github.com/emekalites/react-native-alarm-notification): Also only works for android... And It seems more complex because it is based on implementing local push notification to look similar to an alarm.
3. [react-native-alarm](https://github.com/smartliang/react-native-alarm): The only one that works booth for IOS and Android, but the documentation is super poor, I couldn't figure out how to use it (I think this library doesn't work as you can check [here](https://github.com/smartliang/react-native-alarm/issues/4)).

No one of this solutions seems to be functional in iOS and Android, simultaneously.

There any other solution?

Thanks in advance, this is my first React-Native project, I'm kind of lost in this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i was having the same issue earlier. I tried all kind of third party libraries but some major and minor issues are still and unable to get rid of those, then i decided to implement **react-native-push-notifications**

```js
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';

            PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
               id: 1,
              message: `Reminder Message`,
              date: new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 1000),
              repeatType: 'day',
              // repeatTime: 
              allowWhileIdle: false,
              exact: true,
})
```

For more understanding please see the example given by officials of push-notifications
**https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/tree/master/example**